# How to make button count dynamic in discord.js or discord.py

Tags: javascript, python, discord, discord.js, discord.py

I want to make a role store for an economic bot in discord, where you can buy and set roles, but I have 1 problem, I don’t know how to make dynamic buttons (an indefinite number) for buying, I want to do it like in the screenshot below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5ace.png)

I tried to somehow solve this problem using the nextcord library (Python), but in the end these attempts were unsuccessful, I also started to study discord.js (JavaScript), but there is still not enough knowledge to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a polling where users reaction are the votes in discordjs? here's the script for that, not sure about the buying logic.

```
  const Discord = require('discord.js');
  const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', async message => {
   if (message.content === '!poll') {
    // Create the poll message
    const pollMessage = await message.channel.send('What is your favorite color?');
    
    // Add the emoji reactions
    await pollMessage.react('');
    await pollMessage.react('');
    await pollMessage.react('');
    
    // Create a collector to collect the user reactions (adjust voting time in milliseconds) 
    const filter = (reaction) => reaction.emoji.name === '' || reaction.emoji.name === '' || reaction.emoji.name === '';
    const collector = pollMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
    
    // Create a variable to store the results
    let results = {'': 0, '': 0, '': 0};
    
    // Collect the reactions 
    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
        results[reaction.emoji.name]++;
    });
    
    // Print the results when the collector stops (you can put the buying logic here)
    collector.on('end', () => {
        message.channel.send(`Results: \n: ${results['']} \n: ${results['']} \n: ${results['']}`);
    });
}
});

client.login(YOUR_TOKEN);
```